# TypedQuery equivalent for JPA 1.0

Tags: jpa-2.0

I am quite new to JPA and I am using Apress JPA2 text book to learn it. I was trying to do the first example from the book. This following line of code gives me an error:

TypedQuery query = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Employee e", Employee.class);

saying that TypedQuery cannot be resolved to a type. After struggling for sometime I realised that I am using JPA version 1 which does not contain TypedQuery but just Query interface.

My question is whether there is an equivalent statement in JPA version 1. Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As TypedQuery was introduced from JPA-2.0, have to go for Query interface.

1) Native query to map the result type for the query (loosing portability).

```
Query selectQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT
 e FROM Employee e", Employee.class);
```

2) Creating query & then explicitly casting it to the result type (more preferable).

```
Query selectQuery = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Employee e")
List<Employee> employees = (List<Employee>)selectQuery.getResultList(); //Multiple Result
Employee employee = (Employee)selectQuery.getSingleResult(); //Single Result
```