# [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.gates.cloud.model.something

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to get value from the database, in my case I use List to get the value from the database but I got this error

```
ex = (java.lang.ClassCastException) java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.gates.cloud.model.StaffAttendanceTemp
```

This is my list :

```
List<StaffAttendanceTemp> attendanceTempList = ds.doQuery("SELECT distinct a.staf.stafPK.kod, a.attendancedate FROM StaffAttendanceTemp a"
    + " WHERE a.staf.stafPK.companyid = :companyid")
        .setParameter("companyid", this.getSession().getCompanyid()).getResultList();

System.out.println(attendanceTempList.getClass().getSimpleName());

List<StaffAttendanceTemp> attendanceTempList2 = ds.doQuery("SELECT a FROM StaffAttendanceTemp a"
    + " WHERE a.staf.stafPK.companyid = :companyid")
        .setParameter("companyid", this.getSession().getCompanyid()).getResultList();

System.out.println(attendanceTempList2.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

and this is my loop

```
for (StaffAttendanceTemp attendanceTemprecursive : attendanceTempList) {
    Date timePunchin = null;
    Date timeBreakout = null;
    Date timeBreakin = null;
    Date timePunchout = null;
    Date tarikhPunch = null;

    for (StaffAttendanceTemp attendanceTemp2recursive : attendanceTempList2) {
    }
}
```

how to solve this?

Comment: First of all, try to improve your question by telling the details. Please have a look at [help] as well as the [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections for more information on how to improve your question and increase your chances of getting decent help.

Comment: Can add one more method? The `ds` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem come from here :

```
List<StaffAttendanceTemp> attendanceTempList = ds.doQuery("SELECT distinct a.staf.stafPK.kod, a.attendancedate FROM StaffAttendanceTemp a"
    + " WHERE a.staf.stafPK.companyid = :companyid")
        .setParameter("companyid", this.getSession().getCompanyid()).getResultList();
```

As you can see ,the `ds.doQuery()` return an object which is in this case returning `List<Object>` and not `List<StaffAttendanceTemp>` class. So the error occur because Object class cannot be cast to custom Class without proper step.

> General rule is the following:
>
> If select contains single expression and it's an entity, then result
>   is that entity
>
> If select contains single expression and it's a
>   primitive, then result is that primitive
>
> If select contains multiple
>   expressions, then result is Object[] containing the corresponding
>   primitives/entities So, in your case list is a List.

You can refer here :

[JPA Entity 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700565/jpa-query-getresultlist-use-in-a-generic-way)

[JPA query result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901282/jpa-query-getresultlist)

One of the solution you can try is change the query to this:

```
List<StaffAttendanceTemp> attendanceTempList = ds.doQuery("SELECT distinct a FROM StaffAttendanceTemp a"
    + " WHERE a.staf.stafPK.companyid = :companyid")
        .setParameter("companyid", this.getSession().getCompanyid()).getResultList();
```

Or if you really want a specific parameter only,you need to deal with the object like this:

```
List<Object[]> attendanceTempList = ds.doQuery("SELECT distinct a.staf.stafPK.kod, a.attendancedate FROM StaffAttendanceTemp a"
    + " WHERE a.staf.stafPK.companyid = :companyid")
        .setParameter("companyid", this.getSession().getCompanyid()).getResultList();

for (Object[] listContent : attendanceTempList) {
//deal with Object[] here
}
```

Comment: the ds : 
`public Query doQuery(String query) throws Exception {
        try {
            return entityManager.createQuery(query);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(new StringBuilder().append("(804) Error in doQuery : ").append(e.getMessage()).toString());
        }
    }`